# MySQL: How to do a conditional update?

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to a create an update statement along the following lines:

```
TABLE car: id | owner_id | type | status
```

An owner can have multiple cars.

```
UPDATE car c 
   SET c.type = 1 
     WHERE c.owner_id IN ($ids) 
     AND c.status = [1 IF THIS OWNER HAS A CAR WITH 1, ELSE A CAR WITH 0] // ... ???
```

$ids is reasonably small (under 50 values).

It seems simple but I can't seem to get my head around it because I can't use a SELECT subquery with an UPDATE to the same table.

Anyone?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly what "if this owner has a car with 1..." means. maybe show some sample data and how it should be changed by your update.

Comment: @xenoterracide: Basically, an owner has multiple cars, some with status=1, some with status=0. So I'm looking to do the update on a status=1 row if an owner has it, else do the update on a status=0 row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you have tried a query that fails but unfortunately you have not posted it, so I'm going to guess that it is this:

```
UPDATE car c 
SET c.type = 1 
WHERE c.owner_id IN ($ids) 
  AND c.status = (SELECT MAX(c2.status) FROM car c2 WHERE c.owner_id = c2.owner_id)
```

Posting your actual query would be helpful, but for now I'm just going to assume that this is what you tried. If you have something slightly different, it doesn't matter... the principle is the same. It fails as you as you correctly pointed out because you cannot update and select from the same table in one query. One way to workaround this error is to wrap the select in another select:

```
UPDATE car c 
SET c.type = 1 
WHERE c.owner_id IN ($ids) 
  AND c.status = (SELECT * FROM
                    (SELECT MAX(c2.status) FROM car c2 WHERE c.owner_id = c2.owner_id)
                  AS T1)
```

Surprisingly, this will work even though it seems that it should be equivalent to the first query. Note though that the reason why the original query doesn't work is because it doesn't correctly lock the table. This workaround tricks MySQL into allowing the query anyway, but you should be aware that it may be unsafe to use in a multi-user environment.

Comment: @Mark: Yep, the above query is what I was trying. Your second example would solve the issue... can you elucidate at all why it would be unsafe for a multi-user environment? Thank you.

Comment: @Tom: In this query, the table should be locked for the duration of the update and the select. As far as I understand it, this locking is currently not implemented in MySQL. If the table changes between the select and the update, the result might not be what you expect. I have never seen any problems with doing this though, and I'm not 100% sure that it is definitely unsafe in your situation, but if want to be safe it might be better to write a stored proc where you select first, store the results in a temporary table, then perform the update in a separate statement, instead of this trick.

Comment: I think locking is supported for InnoDB tables but not for MyISAM.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks for the info. Do you happen to know if this is documented anywhere? I have searched for official information about this issue but have been unable to find it.